# Replace 0 in form field with empty by jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a form with some input fields which are showing a 0 instead of just empty when there isn't a value. This is because of the Int fields in de database have a default 0. I cannot change this because of the behaviour of the cms.
But I guess I can remove this 0 with jQuery. I want to replace the 0 for empty if there is only one 0 in all input fields with the class .numeric

How can I do this? I'm not familiar with jQuery.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try/research anything?

Comment: I suggest using your server-side code to only output numbers greater than zero.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I haven't had a chance to check this code but it should empty all fields with the class .numeric that contain 0 only.

```
$(function() {
    $fields = $('.numeric');

    $.each($fields, function() { 
        if ($(this).val() == 0) {
            $(this).val('');
        }
    }    
}
```